# Getopts in bash script with sub-arguments

Tags: linux, bash, getopt, getopts

I would like to be able to run a script like this ( with sub-arguments ):
I need to be able to use short and long options

`./myscript.sh -u myname --delete-config --delete-data`

`./myscript.sh -a myname ..........................`

`./myscript.sh -h`

Actually i have :

```
OPTS=`getopt -o a?d:h?dd?dc? --long apps,delete:,delete-data,delete-config -n 'parse-options' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"


while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --apps ) 
        showHelp
        exit 0
        ;;
    -d | --delete ) 
        username="$2"
        echo $username
        shift 2
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"
       
        # Here i can add argument to the command

        case "$1" in
            -dd | --delete-data ) 
                deleteData
                shift 1
                ;;
            -dc | --delete-config ) 
                deleteConfig
                shift 1
                ;;   
            * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
                showHelp 
                break 
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
    -h | --help ) 
        showHelp 
        break 
        ;;
    -- ) shift; 
        break 
        ;;    
    * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
        showHelp 
        break 
        ;;
  esac
done
```

The result of the script is :

--delete toto --delete-data --delete-config

toto

--delete-data

--delete-config

suppress en cours data

Unexpected option: --delete-config - this should not happen.

I don't understand what i'm making wrong with shift and getopts

Comment: Does it accept sub-arguments with double hypens? I'd guess that the last *) prints the error message.

Comment: I can produce a case where the last sub argument works but not the first sub argument
In the delete -> shift 3

Comment: You need a `while` loop after this line : `# Here i can add argument to the command`

Comment: @Philippe Purpose your solution in answer ( this script can be tested on your side if needed without problem )

Comment: @Philippe With just a loop, it's starting the two scripts but throw error : suppress en cours data
suppress en cours config
Unexpected option: --delete-config - this should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different version :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OPTS=`getopt -o a?d:h?dd?dc? --long apps,delete:,delete-data,delete-config -n 'parse-options' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"


while test "$1" != --; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --apps )
        showHelp
        exit 0
        ;;
    -d | --delete )
        username="$2"
        echo $username
        shift 2
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"

        # Here i can add argument to the command

        while test "$1" != --; do
            case "$1" in
                -dd | --delete-data )
                    echo deleteData
                    shift 1
                    ;;
                -dc | --delete-config )
                    echo deleteConfig
                    shift 1
                    ;;
                * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
                    showHelp
                    break
                    ;;
            esac
        done
        ;;
    -h | --help )
        showHelp
        break
        ;;
    -- ) shift;
        break
        ;;
    * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
        showHelp
        break
        ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: i confirm that your version works, not mine. Mine was only working on my case not with a third sub parameter, your yes. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not working solution, it only works in this case, not with 3 sub parameters

Thanks to Philippe for his comment :
Let me know if you think it's not ok, or purpose better and a confirm as answer :)

```
OPTS=`getopt -o a?d:h?dd?dc? --long apps,delete:,delete-data,delete-config -n 'parse-options' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"


while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --apps ) 
        showHelp
        exit 0
        ;;
    -d | --delete ) 
        username="$2"
        echo $username
        shift 2
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"
        echo "$3"
        while true; do
        case "$1" in
            -dd | --delete-data ) 
                deleteData
                shift 
                ;;
            -dc | --delete-config ) 
                deleteConfig
                shift
                break
                ;;   
            * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
                showHelp 
                break 
                ;;
        esac
        done
        ;;
    -h | --help ) 
        showHelp 
        break 
        ;;
    -- ) shift; 
        break 
        ;;    
    * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
        showHelp 
        break 
        ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Not working solution, it only works in this case, not with 3 sub parameters