# BASH getopt with sub-arugments / sub-options & user input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments, getopt

**UPDATE:**

After playing the with the code, the answer appears to be changing `shift 1 ;;` to `shift 2 ;;` below the input.

I'm not a BASH guru so I will leave a few days for someone to post a better answer.

Apparent answer & line change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# bash myscript2.sh

#=======================================================================
# showHelp [show options]:
#=======================================================================

showHelp()
{

  
  \cat <<- HELP
  
OPTIONS
 -d | --delete :     

HELP

}

deleteData=0

OPTS=`getopt -o a?d:h?D:v? --long apps,delete:,delete-data,delete-config -n 'parse-options' -- "$@"`

args=($@)


if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"

while test "$1" != --; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --apps )
        showHelp
        exit 0 ;;
    -d | --delete )
        username="$2"
        echo $username
        shift 2
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"

        # Here i can add argument to the command
    
        echo "Option: arg1:$1 arg2:$2."

        while test "$1" != --; do
            case "$1" in
                -D | --delete-data )
                    #echo "Option: arg1:$1 arg2:$2." ;
                    deleteData=$2 ;
                    # ANSWER CHANGE ['shift 1 ;;' to 'shift 2 ;;']:
                    shift 2 ;;
                -v | --delete-config )
                    echo deleteConfig
                    shift ;;
                * ) echo "@Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
                    showHelp
                    break ;;
            esac
        done ;;
    -h | --help )
        showHelp
        break ;;
    -- ) shift;
        break ;;
    * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
        showHelp
        break ;;
  esac
done

echo "deleteData: ${deleteData}"
```

==================================

I found this example here, but it doesn't seem to work with inputs for the sub-arguments: [Getopts in bash script with sub-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586372/getopts-in-bash-script-with-sub-arguments)

So this entry:

```
bash myscript2.sh -d asdf -dd 999
```

Results in an error & deleteData is not set to 999 (even though it echos the right argument value).

```
OPTIONS
 -d | --delete :     

d
--
999
Option: arg1:-- arg2:999.
deleteData: 0
```

I think it may have something to do with the options `a?d:h?dd:dc?` & condition `white test`.

myscript2.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# bash myscript2.sh

#=======================================================================
# showHelp [show options]:
#=======================================================================

showHelp()
{

  
  \cat <<- HELP
  
OPTIONS
 -d | --delete :     

HELP

}

deleteData=0

OPTS=`getopt -o a?d:h?dd:dc? --long apps,delete:,delete-data,delete-config -n 'parse-options' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"

while test "$1" != --; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --apps )
        showHelp
        exit 0 ;;
    -d | --delete )
        username="$2"
        echo $username
        shift 2
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"

        # Here i can add argument to the command
    
        echo "Option: arg1:$1 arg2:$2."

        while test "$1" != --; do
            case "$1" in
                -dd | --delete-data )
                    #echo "Option: arg1:$1 arg2:$2." ;
                    deleteData=$2 ;
                    shift 1 ;;
                -dc | --delete-config )
                    echo deleteConfig
                    shift 1 ;;
                * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
                    showHelp
                    break ;;
            esac
        done ;;
    -h | --help )
        showHelp
        break ;;
    -- ) shift;
        break ;;
    * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
        showHelp
        break ;;
  esac
done

echo "deleteData: ${deleteData}"
```

NOTE: I didn't write the original example & don't really care if it needs multi-char options.

If I replace 'dd' with 'x', the input will be correct (from 0 to 999), but it will still throw an Unexpected Option error & call showHelp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I would +1 tjm3772's answer for effort (even though it doesn't solve the problem), but I do not have enough rep.

---

After playing the with the code, the answer appears to be changing `shift 1 ;;` to `shift 2 ;;` below the input.

Apparent answer & line change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# bash myscript2.sh

#=======================================================================
# showHelp [show options]:
#=======================================================================

showHelp()
{

  
  \cat <<- HELP
  
OPTIONS
 -d | --delete :     

HELP

}

deleteData=0

OPTS=`getopt -o a?d:h?D:v? --long apps,delete:,delete-data,delete-config -n 'parse-options' -- "$@"`

args=($@)


if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"

while test "$1" != --; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --apps )
        showHelp
        exit 0 ;;
    -d | --delete )
        username="$2"
        echo $username
        shift 2
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"

        # Here i can add argument to the command
    
        echo "Option: arg1:$1 arg2:$2."

        while test "$1" != --; do
            case "$1" in
                -D | --delete-data )
                    #echo "Option: arg1:$1 arg2:$2." ;
                    deleteData=$2 ;
                    # ANSWER CHANGE ['shift 1 ;;' to 'shift 2 ;;']:
                    shift 2 ;;
                -v | --delete-config )
                    echo deleteConfig
                    shift ;;
                * ) echo "@Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
                    showHelp
                    break ;;
            esac
        done ;;
    -h | --help )
        showHelp
        break ;;
    -- ) shift;
        break ;;
    * ) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
        showHelp
        break ;;
  esac
done

echo "deleteData: ${deleteData}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`getopt -o` only recognizes one-character options. `-dd` is not a valid short option as it is two characters.

`getopt` is interpreting your arguments as:

`-d asdf` -> -d with asdf as an argument

`-dd` ->  -d with d as an argument

`999` -> non-option argument, so `getopt` adds `--` as end-of-options and tacks `999` on after that as a positional argument

The hacky way to get what you want in this case would look something like:

```
-d | --delete )
        username="$2"
        echo $username
        shift 2
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"
        if [[ $1 = '-d' ]] ; then
          shift
          case $1 in
            d) shift ; deleteData=$2 ;;
          esac
        fi
```

This does come with disadvantages though, namely that `-dd 999` can't be followed by any additional arguments because `getopt` is explicitly ending your options when it sees what it thinks is a positional argument.

It would probably be better to just write a custom option parser than use `getopt` in this scenario. Your use case is not really what that tool has in mind.

Comment: I didn't write the original example & don't really care if it needs multi-char options. 

I did suspect the issue you mentioned & tested it earlier.

However, if I replace 'dd' with 'x', the input will be correct, but it will throw an Unexpected Option error & showHelp still.